# Dynamically size UISlider based on audio file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uislider

A user selects a single .mp3 from the MediaPicker. I want to dynamically set the width of a UISlider based on the length of the .mp3 (in seconds). The UISlider is displayed in a UIScrollView which a timer animates/scrolls the UISlider during music playback (similar to how an audio track appears in iMovie).

**My question: How can I set the width of the UISlider so that no matter what the width ( .mp3 length in seconds), the thumb will "scroll" at exactly the same speed and not change dependent upon the length of the song. ie. With a short song and a long song, the thumb should scroll at exactly the same speed because the width of the UISlider has changed according to music length.

I have been at this for 2 days. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of AVAudioPlayer with mp3 file. Now set your slider maximum and minimum value according to audio file played:

Firstly set minimum value of slider.

```
yourslider.minimum = 0;
```

Now to set maximum value in slider using avaudioplayer's duration property which gives total duration of mp3 or any audio file:

```
 yourslider.maximum = ceilf(float)avaudioplayer.duration);
```

Comment: Would casting `avaudioplayer.duration` to an `int` not floor the value?  Would the ceiling be better, as < 1 second of blank space at the right end of the slider seems preferable to losing up to 1 second of the song content?